# Angular ng-if in compile doesn't respond

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create element with angular element and append to some element. The new element has an ng-if the tell it whether it needs to be visible based on a scope variable condition. But for some reason it doesn't respond to the change. This is the code:

```
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: {
    object: '=on'
  },
  compile: function(elem) {
    var td = angular.element('<td></td>' ),
        closeRow = angular.element('<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" ng-if="!object.open"></i>' ),
        openRow = angular.element('<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down" ng-if="object.open"></i>');
    td.append(closeRow ).append(openRow);
    elem.append(td);
    return link;
  }
}

function link($scope, elem) {
  $scope.object.open = false;
  elem.on( "click", function() {
    $scope.$apply( function() {
      $scope.object.open = ! $scope.object.open;
    });
  });
}
```

}

and the html:

```
<tr slide-toggle-row on="post">
  <td>{{post.title}}</td>
    <td>{{post.text}}</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
```

Comment: FYI don't call your linking function's scope `$scope`. It doesn't do a provider lookup, so just call it `scope`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use compile function for this. Try to use link function + $compile service to inject HTML properly hooked up with scope object:

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        object: '=on'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem) {

        var td = angular.element('<td></td>'),
            closeRow = angular.element('<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" ng-if="!object.open"></i>'),
            openRow = angular.element('<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down" ng-if="object.open"></i>');

        td.append(closeRow).append(openRow);
        $compile(td)(scope);

        elem.append(td);

        scope.object.open = false;
        elem.on("click", function() {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                scope.object.open = !scope.object.open;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/25eVRVWRmzBJloYO4QmG?p=preview